# Swift - How to search an array of structs

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3

I have an array of such , such:

```
struct elephants {
 var name: String
 var age: Int
 var location: String
}
```

I then have an array of structs

```
var elephantArray [elephants] = [elephant1, elephant2, elephant3]
```

What I want to be able to do is to search based on elephants.name - so if elephant2.name was "Bob" then when I searched the array based on the name "Bob" then it would return the index position of elephant2.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you read the documentation of `Array`? If you have, you would have found a method called [`firstIndex(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994722-firstindex).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's simple func which will help you:

```swift
func searchElephantIndex(name: String, elephArray: [elephants]) -> Int? {
  return elephArray.firstIndex { $0.name == name }
}
```

If the elephant with the requested name does not exist, the function will return nil.

Answer (score 4):

[firstIndex](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994722-firstindex)

Here the implementation

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

struct elephants {
 var name: String
 var age: Int
 var location: String
}

let elephant1 = elephants.init(name: "A", age: 10, location: "BD")
let elephant2 = elephants.init(name: "B", age: 20, location: "UK")
let elephant3 = elephants.init(name: "C", age: 30, location: "IND")

var elephantArray :  [elephants] = [elephant1, elephant2, elephant3]

if let i = elephantArray.firstIndex(where: { $0.name == "A" }) {
    print("get the \(i)")
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. The only issue I get, is that the value of i is being returned as:  i [Element].index? 1 - which then means that rather than reading 1 the rest of the code is reading [Element].Index? which is screwing the code up

Comment: Would you please elaborate? I have run the code in playground and found `get the 0`

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple way of getting the index:

```
func getIndex(for name: String) {
    for i in 0..<elephantArray.count {
        if elephantArray[i].name == name {
            print(i)
        }
    }
}
```

We iterate through the array and check if the name property of the element matches the one we are looking for, which is specified in the function parameters.

For example:

```
let elephant1 = Elephant(name: "A", age: 1)
let elephant2 = Elephant(name: "B", age: 2)
let elephant3 = Elephant(name: "C", age: 3)

let elephantArray = [elephant1, elephant2, elephant3]

getIndex(for: "B") // prints 1
```

The for loop compares each element's name property to "B" and prints out the index when it matches. This only works because `i` starts at 0 rather than 1, so that it is incremented parallel to the array index, which also starts at 0.

Hope this helps!